# Right Align Button inside DIV

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm more comforable as a back-end developer, but I've got a styling question that has me stumped. I've got a sample of my scenario posted [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jDaM8/1/).

I'm creating a div that is shown/hidden based on a button click to show details for a particular item. That part is working fine, but the layout of this is not quite there.

Here's the basic layout:

```
<div id="signaturePopup">
    <label id="signatureTitle">View Signature</label>
    <div id="signatureImage">
        <!--Contains img-->
    </div>
    <div id="signatureFooter">
        <div id="signatureStatus">
            <!-- Contains another img -->
        </div>
        <label id="signatureUserDetails">Added via JS</label>
        <!-- This is the problematic control-->
        <input id="closeSignature" type="button" value="Close" />
    </div>
</div>
```

With accompanying CSS:

```
#signatureTitle {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
}
#signatureFooter {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
#signatureFooter > div, #signatureFooter > label, #signatureFooter > input {
    display: inline;
}
#signatureFooter > input {
    right: 0;
    align: 
}
#signatureImage > img {
    height: 90%;
    width: 90%;
    border: grey 1px solid;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

I want everything in the div `signatureFooter` pinned to the bottom, which is working fine with my existing CSS. However, inside of that div, I want `closeSignature` to be pinned to the right. I've tried playing with the `position` attribute, like giving it `absolute` but that pushes it outside of the containing div `signaturePopup`. What am I missing? I'm assuming this is easy, but, as I mentioned earlier, CSS is not my strong-suit. Any suggestions on easier/better overall layout would also be welcome.

I am using jQuery to dynamically add the `img` controls, if that opens up any possibilities.
This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244920/how-to-align-a-button-inside-a-div) seemed somewhat similar at first glance, but I don't think I am dealing with any div's being too large.

**EDIT**
Two details I omitted originally are

1. I want the `signatureStatus` and `signatureUserDetails` controls to stay left-aligned. I only want `closeSignature` pinned to the right.
2. `signatureFooter` needs to stay below `signatureImage`, some of the initial answers have them overlapping.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

set the width of the parent div to 100%.So you can float the close button right.

```
#signatureFooter > input {
float:right;
}

#signatureFooter {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jDaM8/4/)

Comment: I assume you mean "right", not "left" here (that's what you have in your fiddle).

Comment: Otherwise, your answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

try float: right css property to pin the close signature to right side.

Comment: Er, yes it does? This exactly answers the question, even if it is not a lot of detail and a great answer it is how to solve his problem

Answer (score 1):

Just so you know, CSS has some weird issues with inheritance, especially around the position attribute. Give the signaturePopup div a position of relative and then try playing with the positioning.

Here is a fiddle that I think does what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/k9HxW/

Also, note that we usually try not to put styles onto IDs in CSS and instead try to give them to classes:

```
.signaturePopup{
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the note on IDs vs classes. I am well-versed in selectors, but had never given much thought to whether there was a "best practice" around which to use.

Comment: @ledbutter As far as I *know,* IDs are reserved for use in HTML where javascript will later manipulate that element in a non-styling related way. It should also be noted that CSS gives different priority to different kinds of selectors (e.g. tag names, classes, or IDs). Check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072365/css-understanding-the-selectors-priority-specificity

Comment: See my update about wanting only the button right-aligned, the rest should stay left-aligned.

Comment: @ledbutter I'm a little confused. You want the styling to match your original fiddle, except you want (just) the close button to be on the right side of the page? If that's what you want, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/44s66/

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the parent element `position: relative;` if you are using `absolute` positioned elements.

css:

```
#signaturePopup {
    position: relative;
}

#signatureFooter {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background: #f7f7f7;
}
```

Finally, a fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jDaM8/5/)